# Using psftp to copy files from unix to windows

Tags: unix, transfer, psftp

I am currently trying to copy a file from a unix server to my local machine. I know you have to use the "get" command but after executing the command, the file is not showing up in my local directory. I really don't know much about unix or psftp so there maybe a chance I am just forgetting something basic. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [psftp tutorial](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~mpilant/math696/psftp.html), there is the 'get' and 'put' command, depending on which box your trying to move the file from.

Honestly, I would download [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php), this has a lot more options, would be faster for you, and a lot easier to use. I use this daily, and I love it.